# echo cancellation on iOS Android?

Tags: android, ios, audio, operating-system

I am trying to find out whether iOS and Android have built in AEC and just can't find it anywhere (surprisingly google search doesn't provide any meaningful results).

Does anyone know if they have it? I know some devices have it built in, but not sure about the OS as a whole.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android provides an option for built-in echo cancellation from 3.0 and up (VOICE_COMMUNICATION AudioSource).
And that isn't guaranteed as well.

Other than that, you can use the Speex AEC.
It can work perfectly when you know how to use it correctly and understand its requirements.